# How to use Multiprocessing Pool on a dictionary input in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

My goal is to to use map reduce aka Multiprocessing pool on a python dictionary. I would like it to map key,value pairs to different cores then aggregate result as a dictionary.

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
elems = {i:i for i in range(1_000_000)}

def func(x):
    return (x, elems[x]**2)

with Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.map(func, elems.keys())
    results = {a:b for a,b in results}
```

This is a bit of a hacky solution but is there a more Pythonic way to receive a dictionary input and produce a dictionary output using a multiprocessing pool in Python?

Comment: it isn't clear what you mean. What input? The input to `pool.map` could just be `elems` (which is in fact equivalent to `elems.keys()`)... so in that sense, the input is a `dict`. So what exactly do you want here? It isn't clear to me. If you want to map key-value pairs, then use `elems.items()`, then `x` will be a key-value pair.

Comment: As an aside, `results = {a:b for a,b in results}` cna just be `results = dict(results)`, in general, `{k:v for k,v in whatever}` can just be `dict(whatever)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can map-reduce easily using a `ProcessPoolExecutor`:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def process(item):
    return (item[0], item[1] ** 2)


def main():
    elems = {i: i for i in range(1_000_000)}

    output = {}

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        results = pool.map(process, elems.items(), chunksize=1_000)

        for result in results:
            output[result[0]] = result[1]

    print(output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here, `results` is an (async) iterator that yields a value each time a result of the parallel processing is available and you can iterate over it for the reduction part. Multiprocessing can be costly because of the interprocess communication of data, thus, you should adapt the `chunksize` parameter to fit your use case.

Some recommendations for multiprocessing:

- never mutate shared state from a function that will be executed concurrently, this will cause data races;
- protect your main function inside an `if __name == "__main__"` or you'll have problems;
- do not declare big data as global state (e.g. your `elems` dictionary) or else it will be replicated in every sub-process, declare a main function instead;
- avoid accessing shared state as much as possible in a concurrently executing function, i.e use `def func(key, value)` instead of using `elems[x]`.

Comment: What's a good way to choose your chunk size? Say I have 3000 elements and 30 cores, is 100 a good choice because this would equally distribute tasks across processes? Or perhaps I'm overthinking it.

Comment: It depends the size of the elements in memory. In general, just try different values and check the speed and memory consumption of your program to estimate the *good* value. Anyway, your suggestion seems optimal.

Comment: I added some details in my answer.